# How to write this linq query to avoid too many query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, aggregate

I have two table Company and Employee. And there relation is Company(one) -  Employee(many).
And I want to concatenate all the Employees' name to a string and output.
I know I can write such a query :

```
  String names = "";
    foreach(var emp in Company.Employee)
    {
         names += emp.name;
    }
```

But If I use this mean, I would load all the employee records into memory, and then make comparison, which is a waste of time and memory, and would low the performance.
So in linq, is it possible to craft such a query that can return all concatenated names within a single SQL ?

Thanks in advance ! Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var employeeNames = context
                       .Company
                       .Where(c => c.Id = 0xF00)
                       .SelectMany(c => c.Employee)
                       .Select(e => e.Name)
                       .ToArray();

var result = String.Join(" ", employeeNames);
```

You can vary the part of the query selecting the company a bit depending on the exact semantics and Entity Framework version. In .NET 4.0 the Entity Framework supports `Single()`. If you don't care about minor semantic differences you can use `First()` instead of `SelectMany()` prior to .NET 4.0.

Comment: do you  know what sql clause the toarray function generate?

Comment: If you have .Net 4.0, you don't need the `ToArray`.

Comment: `ToArray()` just triggers the query execution and turns the `IEnumerable<T>` into an array. As Gabe mentioned you can skip the call in .NET 4.0 because there is a new overload accepting an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Then it's just the same as what I wrote before, it will load all the data into memory, and cascatenate them, but not just return a result ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified variation of Daniel's but I think it should work (making assumptions about the schema)

```
var employeeNames = (from e in context.Employee
                       where e.CompanyId = 0xF00
                       select e.Name)
                       .ToArray(); 

var result = String.Join(" ", employeeNames);
```